# Discard remote changes in SmartGit/Hg

Tags: version-control, mercurial, smartgit

How can I discard remote changes in binary files when merging? There is only menu item to discard changes in local file. When I'm trying to "resolve" it tells it can't do that thing for binary file.

---

Sorry, I've mentioned "resolver" menu but it was "conflict solver". Log http://pastebin.com/xhGuc3du.
Although when I'm using "resolve" I see OK icon in the operations log (right bottom corner) but "conflict" label does not disappear. Log http://pastebin.com/DEDWQSht.

Comment: What's the exact error message? Please post the relevant parts of log.txt from SmartGit/Hg's settings directory (see About dialog).

Comment: Hmm. I'm going to answer my question. I still see "conflict" labels but now (after "resolve") I can commit.

Comment: That's expected: the Conflict Solver will only work for text files, while you can use the Resolve command for all kinds of files and sent content to "ours" or "theirs".

Comment: But how can I tell Resolve command which version to keep - ours or theirs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To discard remote changes, **Local|Discard** should be sufficient. To set your local content either to your own version before the conflict ('ours') or to the remote version ('theirs') use **Local|Resolve** and select the corresponding option there.

Comment: Sorry, I meant **Local** instead of **Modify**.

Comment: "Local|Resolve - select the corresponding option there" - there is no such option to select. Only list with checkboxes of files which I want to resolve.

Comment: Although why do you think "Local|Discard" discards _remote_ changes while it is located in the _Local_ menu?

Comment: Resolving to 'Mine' means taking your 'local' changes and discarding the changes coming in from the merge source, what I guess is what you are referring to by 'remote' changes. When you are rebasing, 'Mine' means the remote changes, though -- that's caused by the nature of how rebase works.